# Pattern match with grepl() function in R

Tags: r, grepl

I am confused on below result on pattern match using `grepl()` function -

```
grepl("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", "2010-04-09") # TRUE
grepl("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", "2010-04-09")  #TRUE
```

Shouldn't I expect the first result to be `FALSE`?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` matches `10-04-09`, so it's TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is correct.

`grepl` is looking for the pattern of xx-xx-xx, where x is a digit, and that does appear in the first query. If you want to query starting from the beginning of the string, you can use the `^` symbol.

For example, if you were to run `grepl("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", "2010-04-09")`, you'd get FALSE, but `grepl("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", "2010-04-09")` would return TRUE.

PS: On the opposite end, `$` indicates the end of the string.